# Not able to get parameter value on click of gantt bar chart of amcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, gantt-chart

This is my gantt bar chart. Actually what I need to get is the value which I am passing like taskname or any other extra value. When I click on any bar the click event is working fine but I am not getting the value of series like task name on click of that bar.
My data format:

```
    {
      "start": "2016-01-01",
      "end": "2016-01-14",
      "color": "#b9783f",
      "task": "Gathering requirements"  //that name i need to find when i click on any bar
    }
```

and my click function is working like :

```
     "listeners": [{
        "event": "clickGraphItem",
        "method": function (event) {
            debugger;
            alert(event.item.category);
        }
    }]
```

If someone has any idea about amcharts can you please help me out. The fiddle link is : http://jsfiddle.net/cuo9d2pz/
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this using:

```
event.item.graph.customData.task
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it via `event.graph.segmentData.task`

Comment: thanks it works but i've achieved it via :  event.item.graph.customData.task